# Not able to test custom exceptions

Tags: python, pytest

There is a class called `PostRecommendationsFuction` which returns some recommendations as a `HttpResponse`. This class also has `custom_exceptions` that invoke the parent class `SearchHttpFunctionBase`'s custom_exceptions. I am writing a test case that mocks the `custom_exceptions`.

```
from azure.core.exceptions import HttpResponseError
from azure.functions import HttpResponse

class PostRecommendationsFunction(SearchHttpFunctionBase):
    def process(self):
         return HttpResponse(body=recommendations.json(by_alias=True, exclude_unset=True),
                        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})

    def custom_exceptions(self) -> dict[Type[Exception], Callable[[Exception], HttpResponse]]:
         return super().custom_exceptions()

class SearchHttpFunctionBase():
    def custom_exceptions(self) -> dict[Type[Exception], Callable[[Exception], HttpResponse]]:
         return {HttpResponseError: lambda e: HttpResponse(status_code=e.status_code, message=e.message)}
```

Mock test cases are below. The function `test_fx_post_recommendations_returns_error` is where I am having trouble not being able to get the appropriate error. The function `test_fx_post_recommendations_returns_200` works as expected. What am I missing?

```
@pytest.fixture
def mock_recommendations(mocker: MockerFixture, test_search_docs: List[SearchResult]) -> SearchResultList:
    mock_recommendations_service = mocker.patch(
    'fx_post_recommendations.post_recommendations.RecommendationsViewService')

    mock_number = '1001'
    mock_recommendations = SearchResultList(target_numbers=[mock_number],
                                        search_results=test_search_docs)
    instance = MagicMock(RecommendationsViewService)
    instance.get_recommendations.return_value = mock_recommendations

    mock_recommendations_service.return_value = instance
    return mock_recommendations


@pytest.fixture
def mock_exception(mocker: MockerFixture) -> MagicMock:
    mock_recommendations_service = mocker.patch(
    'fx_post_recommendations.post_recommendations.RecommendationsViewService')

    instance = MagicMock(RecommendationsViewService)
    instance.get_recommendations.side_effect = HttpResponseError('ResourceNotFoundError')
    instance.exceptions = HttpResponseError('ResourceNotFoundError')
    # instance.side_effect = HttpResponseError('Error')

    mock_recommendations_service.return_value = instance
    mock_exception = instance
    # expected_response = HttpResponse
    # return HttpResponse('ResourceNotFoundError', status_code=404)
    return mock_exception


def test_fx_post_recommendations_returns_200(mock_recommendations: SearchResultList):
    # GIVEN
    request = HttpRequest(method='POST',
                          url='recs/{number}',
                          route_params={'number': mock_recommendations.target_numbers[0]},
                          body=json.dumps({
                              'userId': '123'
                          }).encode('utf-8'))
    expected_response = mock_recommendations

    # WHEN
    get_recommendation_function: PostRecommendationsFunction = PostRecommendationsFunction(
        mtls_enabled=False, incoming_mtls_authenticator=MagicMock())
    response: HttpResponse = get_recommendation_function.process(req=request, context=MagicMock())

    # THEN
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.get_body().decode('utf-8') == expected_response.json(by_alias=True, exclude_unset=True)


def test_fx_post_recommendations_returns_error(mock_exception):
    with pytest.raises(HttpResponseError):
        # with patch('fx_post_recommendations.post_recommendations.RecommendationsViewService'
        #           ) as mock_obj:
        #     mock_obj.side_effect = HttpResponseError('Error')
        # GIVEN
        mock_number = '1001'
        request = HttpRequest(method='POST',
                              url='recs/{number}',
                              route_params={'number': mock_number},
                              body=json.dumps({
                                  'userId': '123'
                              }).encode('utf-8'))
        expected_response = mock_exception
        # WHEN
        get_recommendation_function: PostRecommendationsFunction = PostRecommendationsFunction(
            mtls_enabled=False, incoming_mtls_authenticator=MagicMock())
        response: HttpResponse = get_recommendation_function.process(req=request, context=MagicMock())
        # THEN
        # mock_obj.assert_called_once()
        assert response.status_code == 200
        assert response.get_body().decode('utf-8') == expected_response.json(by_alias=True, exclude_unset=True)
```